# php separating words by using regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I have a string and it contains some words that I want to reach, seperators can be any string that consist of `,`  `;` or a space.

Here is a example:

```
;,osman,ali;, mehmet ;ahmet,ayse; ,
```

I need to take words `osman` `ali` `mehmet` `ahmet` and `ayse` to an array or any type that I can use them one by one. I tried it by using preg function but i couldn't figure out.

If anyone help, I will be appreciative.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$words = preg_split('/[,;\s]+/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

- `[,;\s]` is a character group which means *match any of the characters contained in this group*.
- `\s` matches any white space  character (space, tab, newline, etc.). If this is too much just replace it with a space: `[,; ]`.
- `+` means *match one or more of the preceding symbol or group*.

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/OQrbC3JH)

http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a good site to learn regular expressions.

Comment: the \s is probably still valid for ibrahim's case, however it is not just spaces. the \s set includes tabs and new lines as well. -- Just so no one is confused

Comment: @JonathanFingland: Thank you. I added some information. From my experience `\s` is often more suitable.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use [preg_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) and use [;, ]+ for your regex to split on

```
$keywords = preg_split("/[;, ]+/", $yourstring);
```

Answer (score 1):

Split on non-word characters:

```
$array=preg_split("/\W+/", $string);
```